# What do these ASP.Net user controls (.ascx) in a Tridion Page do?

Tags: asp.net, tridion

I got this code from an SDL Tridion site related to render ASP.Net user controls on the page.

What I understand is the body tag menu, content, search results are .ascx file. But I don't understand the other controls they have used. Can anyone please explain this code snippet?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      <tridion:content ExpectXmlContent="true" XPath="//tcm:Content/tridion:Content/tridion:title" runat="server"/>
    </title>
    <tridion:content templateuri="tcm:47-3016-32" runat="server"/>
    <tridion:track runat="server" xpath="//tcm:Metadata/tridion:Metadata/tridion:category" pageuri="tcm:47-2966-64" />
    <tridion:secure issecured="false" redirecturl="~/login/login.aspx" runat='server'/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <tridion:menu menutype="topnav" runat="server"/>
    <tridion:content templateuri="tcm:47-3052-32" runat="server"/>
    <tridion:searchresults Category="Categories" templateuri="tcm:47-3058-32" runat="server"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: None of those are Tridion-provided, the ones that come with Tridion are documented here: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_325C8293AEEB4BAD93DC3DF606B2AB86 (login required)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the projects web.config file, there should be a `<controls>` tag where there'll be a reference to an assembly that's using the "tridion" tag prefix.

You can then use something like [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) to decompile the assembly and get a clearer idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 9):

These are indeed ASP.NET User Controls as you already concluded. But as far as I know these controls are not part of a standard Tridion installation. So that means they were probably created specifically for your web site by the original implementer. I suggest reaching out to that implementer for documentation and the source code.

That said, from simply glancing over the fragment it looks like:

- the first `tridion:content` looks up the Page title from the Page XML
- the second `tridion:content` renders all Component Presentations on the Page that use the specified Component Template
- the `tridion:track` calls Tridion's personalization-and-profiling module to track a visit to this Page
- the `tridion:secure` uses Tridion Professional Service's Secure Content Delivery module to ensure only properly authorized users have access to this Page
- then `tridion:menu` renders a menu, seemingly unrelated to any item in Tridion
- then another `tridion:content` control renders more Component Presentations, this time the ones with another Component Template
- lastly the `tridion:searchresults` does a query to the Tridion Broker to show a list of related Component Presentations